# Is it safe to modify a trigger on a table that is replicated?

Tags: database, triggers, replication, sybase

Specifically in Sybase 12.5 are there any issues in updating a trigger on a table that is being replicated to another database by Sybase Replication Server.

This could lead to a discussion of whether it's safe to update a trigger on a table in a system that is being actively used, and what the exact semantics are in that case. But I'm not asking this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sybase RS replication is not trigger based but transaction log based system.

So if your trigger does modify data in other replicated tables you will get some side effect.
If your trigger does not modify data in replicated tables you could safely modify this trigger.